# How can I access a folder or file in parent folder JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, directory, shared-directory

I have a web page(`index.hmtl`), which has links to go to pages in the `page` folder. How can I link back the main page from the a webpage in the `page` folder?

File tree:

```
/www
    index.html
    /pages
        pageA.html
        pageB.hmtl
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `../` to access a relative parent folder.

Comment: how about refferring a javascript file from subfolder in the parent folder
ParentFolder/javascriptFolder->jsFile &  
ParentFolder/htmlFolder->htmlfile